# What kind of model to run?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Trying to make a good model for voting habits of congress- dependent variable is "vote", with values being 0- not a member when vote taken,  1 – yea, 6 – nay, 9 – abstain.

Independent variables include party, primary election returns... Will do feature selection to find important variables, which I can do on random forest. Now since vote can be 0,1,6,9. does doing regression make sense? How should I change the dependent variable

Comment: You've represented possible values of the dependent variable using integers, but this labeling is arbitrary. Unlike integers, the values (not member, yea, nay, abstain) have no inherent ordering or distance between them. Rather, they correspond to discrete categories. Since the dependent variable is categorical (with 4 possible values), this is a multiclass classification problem, rather than a regression problem.

Comment: @user20160: Or a multinomial regression. Your comment is pretty much an answer.